# React Native - Text must be rendered withing a <Text> component

Tags: react-native, expo

I am m trying to write an app that just saves and holds data, and I am getting the following error.

> Unexpected text node: . A text node cannot be a child of a < View >. (On Chrome DevTools)

> Text must be rendered withing a  component (On Expo Go simulations)

From what I understand there is a " " (as in the space character) ***SOMEWHERE*** in the code and it wont work because of that, but I have completely no clue where the space can be, as prettier just puts spaces everywhere on its own to style stuff.

It runs fine in the web, but I need it to work on iOS, and when I try to simulate it, this error stops the entire app.

Here is a link to snack.expo with a stripped down version of what im trying to make: https://snack.expo.dev/@vevlex/stringintext

(Right now there is an error because the ID of the added jobs is the same, I'm aware of that and I just didn't get around to doing that yet)

Comment: `App.js` line `69`. Remove the `{""}`. You cannot have comments in JSX using this syntax but using `{/**/}`.

Comment: Omfg... Idk how I didn't see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `{""}` in `App.js`. We need to use `{/**/}` for comments.

Comment: Thanks, tbh I'm not sure how that got there. I honestly think that that was auto filled in.